# How to refer to a variable which is in a common script and the variable name in a file in a UNIX shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have a config file which contains variable names as below:

`config.txt`:

```
ABC

XYZ
```

and the value of those variables are in another script as below:

`basescript.sh`:

```
xyz="Hi"

ABC="Hello"
```

I want to fetch the variable names from config file and refer  to the variable in that script and get the value.

I tried this:

```
mainscript.sh

. /basescript.sh

ABC=`head -1 config.txt`;
echo $ABC
```

The result I am getting is e.g. `ABC` not the value.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the (untested) lines of

```
EVAL='';
for NAME in $(cat 'Config_file.txt'); do
  LINE=$(grep -e "^\\s*$NAME\\s*=") 'basescript.sh'
  test -n "$LINE" && EVAL="$EVAL $LINE ;"
done
test -n "$EVAL" && eval "$EVAL"
```

Explanation:

We cycle through the words of `Config_file.txt`, treating them as variable names, then we isolate the according line in `basescript.sh` and append it to a configuration string if it exists.
If the final configuration string is not empty, we evaluate it, thus setting the variables.

Answer (score 0):

`. /basescript.sh` will create all of the shell variables contained in that file in the environment of `mainscript.sh` when it executes.

You can access the value of the variables with indirect expansion using `${!varname}`. Here is an exaple:

```
[mhawke@localhost ~]$ ABC=123
[mhawke@localhost ~]$ echo $ABC
123
[mhawke@localhost ~]$ varname=ABC
[mhawke@localhost ~]$ echo ${!varname}
123
```

Applying that to your script you can iterate over the variable names in `config.txt` and display their values using the value of `$varname` as the variable name:

```
. ./basescript.sh

for varname in `cat config.txt`
do
    if [[ ${!varname} ]]    # if variable is set and has a value
    then
        echo "Variable name: $varname has value '${!varname}'"
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
Variable name: ABC has value 'Hello'
```

Comment: it working in generally but when i am passing ${!varname} to a function fun as fun ${!varname} which is in another base script, not working

Comment: @saik: your function `fun` will be passed the _value_ of the expanded variable `${!varname}`. How are you accessing the variable inside your function? It should be available as a positional parameter, i.e. $1 for the first parameter. BTW since I have answered the question that you asked, you should upvote the answer and perhaps accept it. If you have another question you should create a new question.

Comment: This sounds like a new question.